# Exclude Specific Folder from file search in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am using below code for files search from directories and sub-directories

How can this code be modified to exclude any specific folder from file search

Like Exclude **Windows ** dir from Drive **C:**

```
procedure FindFilePattern(root:String;pattern:String);
var
  SR:TSearchRec;
begin
  root:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(root);
  if FindFirst(root+'*.*',faDirectory or faHidden ,SR) = 0 then
  begin
      repeat
          Application.ProcessMessages;
          if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory ) and (pos('.',SR.Name)=0) then
             FindFilePattern(root+SR.Name,pattern)
          else
          begin
           if pos(pattern,SR.Name)>0 then Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(Root+SR.Name);
          end;
      until FindNext(SR)<>0;
      FindClose(SR);
  end;
end;
```

I Searched a lot about it but did not find any Appropriate solution

Comment: Your _(pos('.',SR.Name)=0)_ means that you won't enter a directory named "Name with . in the middle". I assume you mean either _SR.Name.StartsWith('.')_ to ignore all UNIX-style "hidden" directories (such as ".NEW"), or _(SR.Name<>'.') AND (SR.Name<>'..')_ for full Windows compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments on your question...

A simple way to exclude some directories is to pass a list of folders to exclude from the search.

In that case you can add a new parameter with the list (`TStrings`) of directories you don't want to explore.
The header would look like this:

```
procedure FindFilePattern(root:String; pattern:String; ExcludedFolders:TStrings);
```

And the call would be like this:

```
var
  EF:TStrings;
begin
  EF := TStringList.Create;
  EF.Add('c:\Windows');
  FindFilePattern(edtRoot.Text, edtPattern.Text, EF);
  FreeAndNil(EF);
```

You must modify your procedure to detect those elements and not explore it:

```
procedure FindFilePattern(root:String; pattern:String; ExcludedFolders:TStrings);
var
  SR:TSearchRec;
begin
  root:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(root);
  if FindFirst(root+'*.*',faDirectory or faHidden ,SR) = 0 then
  begin
      repeat
          Form1.memo1.Lines.Add(Root+SR.Name);
          Application.ProcessMessages;
          if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory ) and (pos('.',SR.Name)=0) then
          begin
            // find if the finded element is in the ExcludedList (i = -1 ==> not finded) 
            var i:integer := ExcludedFolders.IndexOf(Root+SR.Name);
            // it's a directory and not finded in excluded => continue... 
            if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory) and (i=-1) then
              FindFilePattern(root+SR.Name, pattern, ExcludedFolders);
          end
          else
          begin
           if pos(pattern,SR.Name)>0 then
            Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(Root+SR.Name);
          end;
      until FindNext(SR)<>0;
      FindClose(SR);
  end;
end;
```

Another comment is about this line, which is used to return the results. The correct thing would be to use an **output parameter**, instead of making reference from within the function to an element of the interface.

```
Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(Root+SR.Name);
```

Add a new parameter for the list of elements finded:

```
procedure FindFilePattern(root:String; pattern:String; ExcludedFolders:TStrings; Finded:TStrings);
```

The call will be like this:

```
var
  EF, List:TStrings;
begin
  EF := TStringList.Create;     // excluded dirs
  List := TStringList.Create;   // Finded elements
  try
    EF.Add('c:\Windows');
    EF.Add('c:\temp');
    FindFilePattern(edtRoot.Text, edtPattern.Text, EF, List);
    Form1.ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(List);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(EF);
    FreeAndNil(List);
  end;
```

And the procedure would be like this:

```
procedure FindFilePattern(root:String; pattern:String; ExcludedFolders:TStrings; Finded:TStrings);
var
  SR:TSearchRec;
begin
  root:=IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(root);
  if FindFirst(root+'*.*',faDirectory or faHidden ,SR) = 0 then
  begin
      repeat
          // Form1.memo1.Lines.Add(Root+SR.Name);
          Application.ProcessMessages;
          if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory ) and (pos('.',SR.Name)=0) then
          begin
            var i:integer := ExcludedFolders.IndexOf(Root+SR.Name);
            if ((SR.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory) and (ExcludedFolders.IndexOf(Root+SR.Name)=-1) then
              FindFilePattern(root+SR.Name, pattern, ExcludedFolders, Finded);
          end
          else
          begin
           if pos(pattern,SR.Name)>0 then
            // Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(Root+SR.Name);
            Finded.Add(Root+SR.Name);
          end;
      until FindNext(SR)<>0;
      FindClose(SR);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why are you still using the Memo? And as a side note: finded should be found.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Germán Estévez -Neftalí  but what if more than 1 folder need to be excluded ?

Comment: @robertjains That is what the parameter ExcludedFolders:Tstrings is for. Germán has provided an example how to fill it. Just add more lines like that i.e.  `EF.Add('c:\temp');`

Comment: @Sherlock70  I forgot to comment that line. Modified. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use TDirectory.GetDirectories from the unit System.IOUtils.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}
 
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.IOUtils;
const
  IGNORE_DIR = 'System';
var
  c: string;
begin
  try
    for c in TDirectory.GetDirectories('C:\Windows', '*.*',
       function(const Path: string; const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean
       begin
         Result := not SameFilename(SearchRec.Name, IGNORE_DIR);
                                   end) do
    writeln(c);
    readln(c);

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```